# Emacs erlang buffer

Tags: emacs, buffer

I use GNU/Emacs for Erlang programming. I compile my code by issuing <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd>. When I call compile, Emacs opens a new buffer (Erlang). It's half the size of the original window. How can I control the size of this buffer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
(setq compilation-window-height 15)
```

Comment: @shk: `defadvice` on `split-window-vertically` might help here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how Erlang mode does the window splitting. Generally speaking though, the main frame is split into 2 windows vertically using `split-window-vertically` which takes a `SIZE` argument to control the size of the window (check the documentation for further details). You can see if your erlang compilation command uses this and try wrapping/advising it.